# How to START A PYTHON SCRIPT AFTER BOOT on RASPBERRY PI?

Tags: python, pi

I am searching for the best way to AUTO START my python script after boot of my raspberry pi.

I used to use **rc.local** for:

```
sudo python /home/pi/datafolder/program.py &
```

It's not the best way to do it. I had some problems with rc.local because sometimes it stucks on boot.  Thats not cool.

I tried to use crontab, systemd, init.d and something but anyone worked for me.
I need a way like rc.local because my script has prints and it's important to me can read that prints in console during script's work.

Comment: There's no need to use `sudo` in `rc.local`. It's already running as root.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT at us.

Comment: I don't need sudo. But with rc.local it has some probabilities to stuck on infinite loop and I need to re-format the sd card to acesso raspberry again.

Comment: Sorry Chris... It was not my idea to shout. I just wanted to highlight the problem I was presenting for people to identify more easily.